# Cloned repository from Github gives error Design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio

I cloned the material components android example repository from [this URL](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples) to Android Studio by doing File > New > Project from Version Control > Repository URL and using [this link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-examples.git).

It's loaded, but any file I try to view gives me the error "Design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync".

What am I missing here? The Sync Gradle icon does not appear either. It appears for other projects I created on my local machine.

I've posted a screenshot of my project structure.

P.S I'm an absolute newbie to Android.

[image]

Comment: I think you opened the wrong folder, it should have been Reply as the root directory.

Comment: @UrielFrankel Many thanks for that pointer. I managed to get it working. It wasn't a straightforward process. Gradle errors were a plenty, but I managed to get it running in the end.

Comment: I will write an answer for others that are stuck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the wrong folder, it should have been Reply as the root directory.